# Unable to use functions within imported package

Tags: go

My current Directory is setup as follows:

```
-- /webserver
      |
     /ftp
      |-> ftp.go
      |-> go.mod
   |->server.go
   |->go.mod
```

Server.go page heading

```
package main

import (
    [..]
    "../webserver/ftp" // issue package
)

func main() {
    [..]
    ftp.test()
}
```

ftp.go page

```
package ftp

import "fmt"

func test() {
    fmt.Println("YES!")
}
```

Here's the part I cant seem to understand in the console "PROMBLEMS" tab. The ftp.go file gets saved. Before I save the server.go file with "../webserver/ftp/" the console displays this:

[image: before server.go save]

When I save server.go it removes "./webserver/ftp", I went as far as adding it into the go src to make it "ftp" instead of "../webserver/ftp". I get the same result.

[image: after save]

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Basically what i want to accomplish is:

have a functions folder and have the functions in that folder (functions.go) to keep the server.go page as clean as possible.

Comment: Delete the `ftp/go.mod` file please. Do not use relative imports please. Export identifiers that you intend to use outside of the package please. Read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) please.

Comment: @mkopriva I did and i get the following before save "test not exported by package ftp" and after save "undeclared name: ftp"

Comment: @OpenSourceAdvocate you "did" *what* exactly?

Comment: @Flimzy i never had it in the first place, did a few google searches and apparently it worked for someone else but not me :/

Comment: @Flimzy i have move it to the `go src` folder and still get the same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several problems here.

1. `ftp/go.mod` should not exist. While it is possible to have multiple Go modules in a single repository, this is very advanced usage, and is rarely useful. Unless you absoultely *know* that you need this capability, and are already exremely comfortable with creating and publishing Go modules, don't do this.
2. Go does not support relative imports.  `import "../webserver/ftp"` is an invalid import path*. Use the fully qualified import path, i.e. `import "github.com/username/projectname/webserver/ftp"`

   The path to use here depends on the module name you've declared on the `module` line of your your top-level `go.mod` file.
3. You cannot import unexported values.

   You've defined `func test() string` in `ftp.go`. This is unexported, by virtue of beginning with a lowercase letter. Only functions, variables, or other symbols which begin with a capital letter are exported in Go.  Try `func Test() string` instead.

*Some will say "But I used `import ".../foo"` and it worked!".  Yes, it can work under very specific circumstances. But its behavior is not reliable, so you should never rely on this, except in very specific testing types of situations.

Comment: going to give this a try, i actually have not pushed the ftp folder to github yet x_x

Comment: @OpenSourceAdvocate in the import replace "github.com/username/projectname" with whatever your module's path is, i.e. in `webserver/go.mod` the first line is `module <module_path>` so your import should be `import "<module_path>/ftp"`. It not necessary for the `<module_path>` to be a repo url but it is a common and recommended practice.

Comment: @Flimzy I have made a push to github although my url come out like this "github.com/username/repoName/blob/master/ftp/ftp.go". does that work on import or should it be "github.com/username/repoName/ftp/ftp.go"

Comment: @Flimzy I have now configure the import to take "ftp" although the results stay the same.  `test() not declared by package ftp`. i have updated the test function

Comment: `test()` is still (and will always be) an unexported name. You must capitalize the first letter.

Comment: @OpenSourceAdvocate please read the short [Exported Identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) section from the Go language's spec, and re-read it as many time as necessary for you to completely comprehend what it is saying.

Comment: @mkopriva honestly i was so tired, i took a break for a bit. Goin to get back to it. Have re-read Exported Identifiers again.